# how to pass a woocommerce product name to contact form7

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-contact-form-7

i wanna when the user click on the button like this
https://stupremat.tn/produit/distributeur-dhuile-en-fut-mobile-charg-de-batterie-f00263200/
it pass the name of product to a textbox in contact form
please help me

Comment: It seems that this plugin has been used by the referenced site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-quote-or-enquiry-contact-form-7/ It does the same thing.

Comment: yes this is what i want but i want it to open a form not a poppup